# Declaring multiple ifstream makes code crash

Tags: c++, g++, ifstream

I just installed *mingw* on my **Windows 10** computer and wanted to code a program that read two files. I immediately faced a frustrating bug with *ifstream*: **when I declare more than one *ifstream*, the program seems to crash** (nothing is logged although the first line cout some text).

The following code compiles and logs "test" in the console:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "test" << endl;
    ifstream test;

    return 0;
}
```

The following code compiles but seems to crash at runtime, nothing is logged:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "test" << endl;
    ifstream test;
    ifstream test2;

    return 0;
}
```

I tested the exact same codes on a macOS Mojave and both codes work and log "test".

I guess the issue is related to the g++ installation but I'd like to know what's really happening and how I can fix this on Windows.

Comment: Interesting, perhaps some aspect of the installation is corrupted. Maybe try re-installing? The stack trace of the crash might hint at what might be the issue.

Comment: What version of GCC? How do you build the second program? What flags are you giving the compiler and linker? Have you tried to check the generated machine code to see what it does? Have you tried to catch the crash in a debugger to when and where it happens?

Comment: I tested the code with the apple clang compiler, and also with gcc-8 (both of them on a mac). I didn't get any crashes, so there might be something wrong with your installation. By any chance are you this guy? https://xkcd.com/1316/

Comment: I've tried your code on Code::Blocks with the GNU GCC COMPILER (the default compiler) and nothing occured. Maybe something during installation has gone wrong. Try reinstalling it, or move to another compiler or even better to a full IDE